# How to make my webpage opened in IE 11 browser to be always on foreground unless I minimize it?

Tags: c#, com, internet-explorer-11, activex

I have to make the browser window(IE 11) that opens my web page to be always on foreground until minimizes it.
Wrote a C# activex dll, registered it. 
The activex dll implements a simple 'Hello world' printing. The code looks like.

```
namespace SampleActX
{

    [ProgId("SampleActX.SampleActX")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [Guid("7F6A5914-9C8A-4977-AF5B-DE9D45E01B44")]
    [ComVisible(true)]

    public class SampleActX
    {
        [ComVisible(true)]
        public string SayHello()
        {
            return "Hello World!";
        }


    }
}
```

Embedded the dll inside the html like below.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
   <head>
          <title>SampleActX webpage</title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <OBJECT id="SampleActX" classid="clsid:7F6A5914-9C8A-4977-AF5B-DE9D45E01B44" codebase="SampleActX.cab"></OBJECT>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            try {
                var obj = document.SampleActX;
                if (obj) {
                    alert(obj.SayHello());
                } else {
                    alert("Object is not created!");
                }
            } catch (ex) {
                alert("Some error happens, error message is: " + ex.Description);
            }      
        </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can we control the IE parent window to make it always on foreground(like how the task manager window is working) from the activex dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried the below code and it worked fine.

namespace SampleActX
{

```
[ProgId("SampleActX.SampleActX")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[Guid("7F6A5914-9C8A-4977-AF5B-DE9D45E01B44")]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);
[ComVisible(true)]

public class SampleActX
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public string SayHello()
    {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
    public void SetIEWindowOnTop()
    {
        var myId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;//Fetches the pid of the current tab in IE only

        var query = string.Format("SELECT ParentProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE ProcessId = {0}", myId); //Finding the actual IE window handle
        var search = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", query);
        var results = search.Get().GetEnumerator();
        results.MoveNext();
        var queryObj = results.Current;
        var parentId = (uint)queryObj["ParentProcessId"];
        var parent = Process.GetProcessById((int)parentId);

        IntPtr windoHandle = parent.MainWindowHandle;//Fetches the parent window handle

        var bresu = SetWindowPos(windoHandle,   //Sets the window on Top
                    HWND_TOPMOST,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                   SWP_NOSIZE|SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
    }

}
```

}

Calling the SetIEWindowOnTop() from html as explained in the question will do the magic.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, When you launch the IE, It will get launch above all windows. Which OS you are using for testing?

In JavaScript, You can refer code below to explicitly do it.

```js
function sample_window() {
 newwindow = window.open('https://microsoft.com', 'popup_return',     'menubar=no,history=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=800,height=600');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
   }
```

If you are using VBA or any other script then you can first hide the browser window and again make it visible will bring the IE window in foreground.

Comment: Yeah when you launch IE it will be always above all other active windows present. I just wanted to make the IE window always on fore ground using an activex dll.
Ofcourse the Operating system is Windows(windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

"I have to make the browser window(IE 11) that opens my web page to be always on foreground until minimizes it." - this is actively hostile... whoever came up with that requirement hates users;

It sounds like what you're actually after is "kiosk mode"; you can do that very easily simply by making whatever shortcut they're using:

```
iexplore -k {url}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not my requirement. Thanks for your time.